# Giving a slave multiple wives

Tags: halacha, number, marriage, slave-serve-eved-avadim, mishpatim

The posuk says I can provide my Jewish servant with a slavewoman to make me children-slaves. Can I give him multiple wives?

Comment: You could improve this question by pointing to the pasuk you refer to.

Comment: As always CYLOR

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Rambam*, [*Avadim* 3:5](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/c503.htm#6), explicitly addresses your question, and the answer is 'no'.